# ef core 2.2: Ho to setup cascade delete with foreign key in dependant

Tags: foreign-keys, entity-framework-core, relational-database, ef-core-2.2

I've set up a code first db with some base entities like "Participant", "Organizer" or "School". They all may have a dependant child entity called "Person". Because such Persons may belong to any of these main entities, the main entities hold a foreign key "PersonId" and a navigation property "Person".

But as far as I know EF decides by location of the foreign key which entity is dependant – in this case the main entities – and which is principal – in this case "Person".

Accordingly cascade delete does not work as I need it: deleting a "Participant" should delete its "Person".

I annotated the "Person" properties with [Required] and indeed the DB states that "PersonId"-columns are decorated with a cascade-delete-constraint:

`CONSTRAINT FK_Participants_Persons_PersonId FOREIGN KEY (PersonId) REFERENCES Persons (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE`

But removing the main entity (with eager loaded person) and calling SaveChanges does not delete the person.

So how could I achieve Persons are deleted on delteig their main entities?

Comment: Cascaded delete deletes records containing the foreign key. If 3 tables refer to `Person` you can't ever have the `Person` deleted automatically if one of the child records is deleted. That may break the other 2 FKs.

Comment: Ok. thx. That reads as answer: "No way". But what would you do to achieve this? Manual deletion or schema change? I can'T imagine no one else has this dependency configuration.

Comment: I tried to explain that you can't delete a `Person` just like that when one of its dependent records is deleted. It needs checking if no other dependents refer to the same records so one way or another you have to write code achieving this. Stored procedure/trigger/business logic.

Comment: What you are describing looks more like TPT inheritance model, which is not currently supported. There is no automatic way to cascade delete in the opposite direction - this comes from relational database rules and has nothing to do with EF Core. So even with the TPT, the deletion of the derived entity will be redirected to deleting the base entity. Simply do the same - instead of deleting (`dbContext.Remove`) the `Participant`, `Organizer` or `School` instances, delete (`Remove`) their loaded `Person` navigation property.

Comment: Dough! Thanks. I would accept this as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Ivan mentions in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022755/ef-core-2-2-ho-to-setup-cascade-delete-with-foreign-key-in-dependant/57034967#comment100577462_57022755):

> What you are describing looks more like TPT inheritance model, which is not currently supported. There is no automatic way to cascade delete in the opposite direction - this comes from relational database rules and has nothing to do with EF Core. So even with the TPT, the deletion of the derived entity will be redirected to deleting the base entity. Simply do the same - instead of deleting (dbContext.Remove) the Participant, Organizer or School instances, delete (Remove) their loaded Person navigation property.